# how to override create function Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm creating Odoo model and i wanna trigger a function on create

*More infos:

*Class Tour:

```
class obj_tour(osv.osv):
    _name = "obj.tour"
    _description = "Objet tour"
    _columns = {
       'id_trans' : fields.many2one('obj.gtransport',"Transport",selection=_get_selection_transport,required = True),# foreign key
    }
    ...
```

*Class Transport

```
class obj_gtransport(osv.osv):
    _name = "obj.gtransport"
    _description = "Objet gtransport"
    _rec_name = "matricule"
    _columns = {
        'est_dispo': fields.boolean( "Disponible"),
    }
    ...
```

i want to trigger when i use a transport in a tour the transport will change the (est_dispo boolean to false)

*Photos:
[image]
[image]

I tried to override the create function but it doesn't change the value of the boolean

Pic:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class obj_tour(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'obj.tour'
    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        record = super(obj_tour, self).create(values)
        if 'id_trans' in values:
            trans_id = values['id_trans']
            trans_model = self.env['obj.gtransport']
            domain = [('matricule', '=', trans_id)]
            trans_ids = [idn.id for idn in trans_model.search(domain)]
            ts = trans_model.browse(trans_ids)
            for obj in ts:
               #obj.est_dispo = False
                obj.write({'est_dispo' : False})
        return record
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Override the create method of tour object & assign Boolean to false in transport object.

Comment: Can you give me an example please

Comment: Have checked your code, seems problem in your domain. You compare id with string.